# the URL 'admin/content/node' created by 'content' views in drupal 8 isn't available

Tags: views

[image]

[image]

I'm beginner of drupal8.When I call the url "localhost/admin/content/node",  will show "The requested page could not be found". in the preview of this views,the url is 'admin/content' and it's available. Why did this change it？  someone can help me?

Comment: did you flush the cache?

Comment: i clear the cache(drush cr) ,but it's no change

Comment: @mingyuwang I just checked this view. seems this is a bug. But why did you bother about it? I mean did you get any issues for that path?

Comment: @KrishnaMohan  I'm just a bit strange it. additionally,in code the function SystemController::overview is responsible for the routing  'admin.content',but i cann't debug into it when call the url 'admin/content'.Did views module overrided this path created by system module?